# How to track GTM event once even after the page reloaded

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set up a trigger for the visibility of an element that is located on the page after payment. The problem is that this page automatically reloads every 10 seconds. The trigger fires on every load, which distorts my analytics.

I cannot specify for the tag "Once per event", because the same client can make another order and get to this page (on another day). The page does not have a custom URL, so it only remains to track it by the visibility of a unique element (success icon)

How can I make it so that the event is only registered once, even if the user reloads the page himself or the browser does it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could fix it with is by setting a cookie after you send your event. And make a blocking trigger to block it from firing if the cookie is set.

Make sure to set appropriate expiry time for that cookie.

A more complex, but firm implementation would involve your web-dev team. So that the event would rely on the actual payment being sent rather than some page loading or a cookie being there. It should also be fairly easy for the front-end. They just need to add a dataLayer event push to the payment's success callback.

Answer (score 0):

For the event you are capturing on visibility, send the payment id or some sort of id that's unique to that particular payment as part of the event label.

This way all the payments will be captured will have a unique label and you can either count the number of rows for the number of payments OR the "Unique Events" metric (note, if the user is allowed to come back to this page in a new session, then the event will trigger again and the "Unique Events" metric will increment by 1 for that event, so if this is the case, count the number of rows)

Better yet, use e-commerce features in GA and capture this as a transaction.